# Pythin turtle x,y position means its *centre,* not the bottom-left hand corner. any way to change this?

Tags: python, python-turtle

I am more used to pygame where displaying graphic at x,y means at the bottom-left hand corner of the rectangle of the image.  This makes collision detection nice and easy.  Unfortunately in turtle, the turtle x,y, position means its *centre* which is a pain in the neck for collision detection, because you have to faff about taking the x and y lengths of the image, dividing by two and subtracting that from the centre x,y position to get the 'real' x,y position, and then it's never quite clear whether the division is going to end up one pixel wrong from where you expect it :-(
Is there any way to get a turtle image to display in this way?   Or if not, is there any other way to display an image at (x,y) in turtle where x,y means the bottom-left-hand corner, not centre?
thank you :-)

Note: this centre position is not a problem when your images are exactly the same size, as they are going to be offset by the same x-offset and y-offset, but become a real problem when the images are of different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, to set the lower-left corner as 0, 0.

```
import turtle as trt
turtle, screen  = trt .Turtle(),  trt .Screen()

Width, Height  = 800, 600
screen .setworldcoordinates( 0, 0,  Width, Height )  ##  lower-left, top-right
```

Or if you're used to coordinate-space where the top-left is origin, and positive Y values go down, such as in [Love2D](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics) then:

```
import turtle as trt
turtle, screen  = trt .Turtle(),  trt .Screen()

Width, Height  = 800, 600
screen .setworldcoordinates( 0, Height,  Width, 0 )  ##  lower-left, top-right
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setworldcoordinates